# pm2-runtime fails to start cluster

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, pm2

I've a very basic nodejs application with express server which does just this.

```
const express = require('express');
const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();
app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("Connected on ${PORT}");
  }
});
```

My `pm2` configuration looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name      : 'node-webpack-babel-starter',
    script    : './dist/backend.js',
    env: {
     NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production : {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
    instances: 'max',
    output: './logs/out.log',
    error: './logs/error.log',
    log: './logs/combined.outerr.log',
  }],
  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : 'node',
      host : '<>',
      ref  : 'origin/master',
      repo : 'git@github.com:repo.git',
      path : './dist/backend.js',
      'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
    }
  }
};
```

According to [pm2-runtime](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/integration/heroku/), we can use the following command to start a server in production environment.

```
pm2-runtime start ecosystem.config.js --env production
```

I tried running on my local box, only one instance is up and all others failed.
Below is the log:

```
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.285Z] PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.349Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:0
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.357Z] PM2 log: App name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:0 online
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.361Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:1
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.367Z] PM2 log: App name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:1 online
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.369Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:2
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.380Z] PM2 log: App name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:2 online
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.391Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:3
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.411Z] PM2 log: App name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:3 online
Example app listening on port 4000!
Example app listening on port 4000!
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.730Z] PM2 log: App [node-webpack-babel-starter] with id [2] and pid [22967], exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.733Z] PM2 error: Cancelling versioning data parsing
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.734Z] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:2
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1335:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1383:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1470:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/box/mien/webpack-node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.listen (/home/box/mien/webpack-node/dist/webpack:/src/main.js:9:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/box/mien/webpack-node/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:22:1)
    at module.exports (/home/box/mien/webpack-node/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:74:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/box/mien/webpack-node/dist/backend.js:78:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
Example app listening on port 4000!
[2018-08-22T07:50:13.754Z] PM2 log: App name:node-webpack-babel-starter id:2 online
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
```

On running `pm2 ps`,I see this
[image]

<strike>Interestingly, it works fine when I run `pm2 start`.</strike>

---

Update event on `pm2 start` only one instance is up all others are down tying to connet to `4000` port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to mention the `exec_mode` attribute in my `ecosystem.config.js`.

If we want to run in cluster mode we need to `exec_mode: 'cluster'`.

See [discussion](https://github.com/keymetrics/doc-pm2/issues/186#MDEyOklzc3VlQ29tbWVudDQxNDk1NzUxNA==).

Comment: It's cluster_mode, not cluster